# How to setup wiremock with angular 8 application?

Tags: angular, mocking, angular8, wiremock

How to mocking REST API With WireMock using angular 8 application
Can you please provide me the steps for the WireMock setup with Angular 8.

http://wiremock.org/

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. start a standalone instance of WireMock server
2. point your Angular services to a WireMock instance (e.g. change host, port)

If you want to use WireMock for integration/E2E test you need to configure Protractor to start/stop WireMock standalone instance before/after executing tests. Protractor provides beforeLaunch() and afterLaunch() callback functions which can be used to wire test dependencies.

Good example of Angular and WireMock integration for integration/E2E testing can be found here: https://allthingsangular.com/angular-and-wiremock-integration-for-ui-testing/

Official documentation on how to run a standalone instance:
http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/